# Fetching Data from Firestore Collections snapshot.hasdata returns Null

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, snapshot

So I have been following a tutorial from YouTube and when I was trying to fetch the "username" from the collection named "users" through Stream snapshot, it returns null.

Aim: Display the available users when search button with username is clicked.

Here is the code below:

```
  bool isSearching = false;
  Stream? usersStream;

  TextEditingController searchUsernameEditingController =
      TextEditingController();

  onSearchBtnClick() async {
    isSearching = true;
    setState(() {});
    usersStream = await DatabaseMethods()
        .getUserByUsername(searchUsernameEditingController.text);
        
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget searchUserList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: usersStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                    return Image.network(ds["imgUrl"]);
                  })
              : Center(child: Text("No Users Found"));
        });
  }
```

From DatabaseMethods():

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getUserByUsername(String username) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("username", isEqualTo: username)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Always shows "No Users Found" Message

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that new value for streambuilder is released when onSearchBtnClick is called.

Try this.

```
onSearchBtnClick() async {
  isSearching = true;
  setState(() {});
}

Widget searchUserList() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: DatabaseMethods()
        .getUserByUsername(searchUsernameEditingController.text),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('called');
      // confirm that print is called when onSearchBtnClick is called.
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return Image.network(ds["imgUrl"]);
              })
          : Center(child: Text("No Users Found"));
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: The argument type 'Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<dynamic>?'.

I get the error for your code but I had to add Future around Widget searchUserList() and I am not receiving 'called' when the search button pressed!